# Refreshing TreeView Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I want to refresh my treeview after updating/deleting records from DB, but it always shows me the same data unless the application closes. Any idea?

I'm showing the window as a Tk() and with .mainloop, for reference.

I've tried clearing the treeview with Treeview.delete and populating the treeview again, but with no results.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: Hi there. I'll post the code in a few hours.

Comment: Hi again. Trying to showing you my code I have discover that my problem is that the data from the database don't get refreshed, even when I call my search method over and over. Any idea in that regard??